# bootstrap popover won't work on the first click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

If I do the first code, it won't show on the first click, but will work properly in the 2nd and other clicks.

```
$('#addContaButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = '/Conta/Create';

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#addContaButton").popover({
                html: true,
                content: data,
                title: function () {
                    return "Adicionar nova conta";
                },
                template: '<div class="popover popover-conta"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h2 class="popover-title"></h2><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>',
                show: true
            });
        },
        async: false,
        error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
            alert("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar criar uma conta. Por favor, entre em contato.");
        }
    });

});
```

If I change the end of popover function like this, it will do the opposite, it will work ONLY on the first click, but will stop working on the 2nd, 3rd...

```
$('#addContaButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = '/Conta/Create';

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#addContaButton").popover({
                html: true,
                content: data,
                title: function () {
                    return "Adicionar nova conta";
                },
                template: '<div class="popover popover-conta"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h2 class="popover-title"></h2><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
            }).popover('show');
        },
        async: false,
        error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
            alert("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar criar uma conta. Por favor, entre em contato.");
        }
    });

});
```

I can't understand why...

Comment: looks interesting, could you please share ur html or make some fiddle

Comment: not sure what's wrong with your code. I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/4n70fd7e/) for you, but I haven't found a fix yet. What you're trying to do is pretty similar to this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/3yddm4rx/), maybe this helps.